# WIX: How to register an Application to a URL Protocol?

Tags: url, wix, protocols, wix3.5

In WiX you can register file types easily:

```
<ProgId Id="MyApp.File" Description="MyApp File" Icon="MyAppEXE" IconIndex="0">
  <Extension Id="ext" ContentType="application/x-myapp-file">
    <Verb Id="open" Command="&amp;Open" TargetFile="MyAppEXE" Argument="&quot;%1&quot;"/>
  </Extension>
</ProgId>
```

What if I want to **register an URL protocol**, as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767914%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)? Obviously, it has no extension so where would I put the `Verb` tag? Or should I use another approach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt there's an out-of-the-box feature for this in WiX (probably, in 3.6?), but as far as I can see by the link you provided, the process of registering a URL protocol is adding a bunch of entries to the system registry. Hence, you can add RegistryKey/RegistryValue elements manually to emulate this.

Comment: Thanks! I believe this is the right way to go. The most straight-forward solution is to export a valid protocol entry from the Registry, and then run it through heat.exe. This will produce the necessary RegistryKey/RegistryValue elements.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but do you have any example of the wix code used? Thanks.

Comment: @JérémieBertrand, it was just a thought from the top of my head that time, with no code sample at hand

Answer (score 25):

Just to add the code of the @Yan Sklyarenko's answer:

```xml
<Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="{206C911C-56EF-44B8-9257-5FD214427965}">
           <File Source="$(var.MyMainProgram.TargetPath)" />
           <RegistryKey Root="HKCR"
                 Key="protocolname"
                 Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall">
             <RegistryValue Type="string" Name="URL Protocol" Value=""/>
             <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="URL:name of the protocol"/>
             <RegistryKey Key="DefaultIcon">
               <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="MyMainProgram.exe" />
             </RegistryKey>
             <RegistryKey Key="shell\open\command">
               <RegistryValue Type="string" Value="&quot;[INSTALLFOLDER]MyMainProgram.exe&quot; &quot;%1&quot;" />
             </RegistryKey>
           </RegistryKey>
         </Component>
```

- `MyMainProgram` is a reference to my main project in the wix setup project
- `protocolname` is the name of the protocol used in the url: `protocolname://`
- `name of the protocol` is the formal name of the protocol